# Can't find local folder in Sychronized pespetcive

Tags: eclipse, egit

Some files conflict in the Synchronized Perspective,but I can't find the specific file.So what's the meaning?

Comment: A file (as in the text of your question) or a folder (as in the title)? Please say what your goal is and the steps you have taken so that someone else can reproduce it. Show us what you see with a screenshot. Please note that synchronizing in Git is a different thing than synchronizing in SVN.

Comment: Sorry for that.I will show you my steps later. Many thanks.